# JQuery - Showing Wrong and Right icons for Validation

Tags: jquery, html, css, validation

I have a form and JQuery validation.  Everything works fine.  Instead of showing messages, I want to show icons.

The wrong icon is working, but I have some problem with the right icon.  When input is a right format, I see `class="valid"` in the syntax `<input class="valid"...>`.  I try to display a right icon after `<input..>` by using `class="valid"`.  The right icon shows right on the text field and the text field disappears.  [LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/6y2rwvae/9/)

Please help.

HTML

```
<form method="POST" id="TestForm">
    <input name="txtIn" type="text" id="txtIn">
    <p></p>
    <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

CSS

```
label.error:after {
    content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    background: url("http://dummyimage.com/15x15/de1417/de1417.png") no-repeat;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.valid{
    margin-left:10px;
    background: green;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}
```

JS

```
$('#TestForm').validate({
    rules: {
        txtIn: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [8, 16]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtIn: {
            required: "Please enter something",
            rangelength: "Icon"
        }




    }
});
$('.valid').after('<div class="valid"></div>');
```

Comment: your `after()` is only going to be called on page load and the valid class doesn't exist then

Comment: @ Charlie, Thank you!  but this this case, what I have to use instead of `after()`?

Comment: can use `highlight` and `unhighlight` options to do your own manipulation

Comment: Just updated my answer, possibly with a working solution for the valid icon.

Comment: @abcidd To avoid extended comments below the answer - I've just updated your Fiddle, hope this will work now as intended.

Comment: @abcidd Added a new approach in updated answer.

Comment: @ Matthias, Sorry I was out for 2 days. Update 4 is a nice approach!  Thank you so much!  You wrote a great code on focusInvalid: false, focusCleanup: true, and onkeyup.  They work so smoothly! Amazing...  However, I didn't get `  onfocusout: function (element) {
        this.element(element);
    },`  Please explain.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the validation in the Fiddle is not always working for correct validation, but you can try to adjust `$('.valid').after('<div class="valid"></div>');` to `$('.valid').after('<div class="validicon"></div>');` and rename your class `valid` to `validicon`. Otherwise the input that will be set to class valid will be applied the css with width 15px etc and therefore not be visible.

**Update:** For the follow-up issues mentioned in the comments: You can try to add display:inline-block; to class erroricon. And as kind of second workaround - if it's ok for you to display kind of an erroricon inside the input instead of next to it, an easy way would be this:

```
input.valid {
   background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/15x15/00ff11/fff.png&text=+');
   background-position: top right;
   background-size: 15px 15px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

**Update 2:** I've just checked the options for the validate plugin. It's possible to add a label for valid elements by extending your settings for `validate()` like this:

```
$("#TestForm'").validate({
   // keep your other settings/options for rules
   // and messages here and add:
  success: function(label) {  
   label.addClass("valid");
  }
});
```

As mentioned in the comments, it's only possible to use css pseudo elements like `:after` or `:before` for container elements, not for elements like `input` or `image`. Good explanation for this provided at this comment by Robert Koritnik: [Can I use the :after pseudo-element on an input field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field#comment-5133582). In case it's possible to add a label with approach suggested above, you can add css for `label.valid:after {...` in the same way as for `label.error:after`.

**Update 3:** For the next approach mentioned in the comments by OP - as adding the label with class valid doesn't seem to work - I just adjusted the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y2rwvae/15/).
HTML adjustment - I moved the `<span class="add"></span>` after the `<input>` instead of wrapping the input in the span.
jquery adjustment:

```
if ($('#TestForm input').hasClass('valid')) {
  $('.add').addClass('validicon');
 } else {
  $('.add').removeClass('validicon');
}
```

As mentioned, if the input is valid, the Fiddle throws a `network error 403 CSRF verification failed`, but it should work on the actual site.

**Update 4:** New approach using the options of jquery validate instead of trying a workaround. Adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rz6bgyfa/) to display valid icon on submit without sending the form.

**HTML:**

```
<form id="TestForm">
 <input type="text" id="txtIn" name="txtIn" />
 <p></p>
 <button id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-left:10px;
 width: 15px;
 height: 15px;
}
label.error {
 background-color: red;
}
label.valid {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

**jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var messages = {
    'txtInRequired': ""
  };

  $('#TestForm').validate({
    rules: {
        txtIn: {
            required: true,
            rangelength: [8, 16]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        txtIn: messages.txtInRequired
    },
    onfocusout: function (element) {
        this.element(element);
    },
    success: function (label, element) {
        if ($(element).hasClass("valid")) {
            label.addClass("valid");
        }
    },
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        alert('form is valid');
        return false;
    },
    focusInvalid: false,
    focusCleanup: true,
    onkeyup: false
  });
});
```

For reference for these adjustments: http://jqueryvalidation.org/category/plugin/

Short explanation:
Setting `focusInvalid: false`: The input won't get focus when the form was submitted and the input is invalid, necessary to combine with  `focusCleanup: true` : when the input gets focus, validation is "cleaned", so the error or icon label won't be displayed. `onkeyup: false` : on enter the input is not validated. And finally: the `success: function (label, element) { .. }` adds class valid to the label in case the element is valid.

Reference: http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/

Comment: @ Matthias, Thank you very much again!  I try your direction, but it doesn't work out.  I also try `$('input .valid').addClass('validicon').after('<div class="valid"></div>');` it doesn't work, either.

Comment: @abcidd I've just adjusted my answer, $('.valid').after('<div class="validicon"></div>'); could work.

Comment: @ Matthias, Thank you!  I try, but it doesn't work out.

Comment: @abcidd Can you check if the div "validicon" is added after the input?

Comment: It doesn't show `.validicon` when the format is right.  If I use `$('.valid').after('<div class="valid"></div>');` the icon shows, but it shows right on the text field and the text field disappears.

Comment: @abcidd Updated my answer with a guess and another workaround. Fiddle is just not working for correct validation, than it would be easier to check what's going on.

Comment: @ Matthias, I have tried this: I don't need to have `$('.valid').after('<div class="valid"></div>');` and in CSS I added  input.valid:after{
   content:"";
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left:10px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
} When I inspected HTML, I saw `input.valid:after` there, but it doesn't show on the browser!!! I wonder why???

Comment: @abcidd It doesn't show in the browser because pseudo-elements like :before and :after only work for container elements, not for e.g. inputs (also not for images). For detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587669/css-after-pseudo-element-on-input-field#comment-5133582

Comment: Thank you very much, Matthias!  so that it is not a right way to approach.

Comment: @ Matthias, You are right! pseudo-element doesn't work on `<input>`.  I also try `success: function(label) {..` as your direction, it doesn't work, either because when input is a right format, the `<label>` is inactive, unfortunately![LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/6y2rwvae/13/).  From this point, I think when input is a right format, the `<input>` will automatically add `class="valid"`, so that I write `if( $('input .valid') == 'true' ){
    $('.add').addClass('validicon');
}`, but it doesn't work!  Please take a look at the [LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/6y2rwvae/14/).  What is wrong here?

Comment: @ Matthias, Good News, after `<input...>`I add `<i class="validicon"></i>` and in CSS, I write `input.valid + i.validicon{....` it works [LIVE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/6y2rwvae/17/).  However, when I try to enter a wrong format and hit tab, it shows the error, then I go back to edit to a right format and hit tab, the right icon doesn't show! this is because `<label id="txtIn-error" class="error"...></label>` is already in the code.  Do you know where to delete this error label in the jquery.validate.js? I try to find it out, but I have no clue!